# How to limit column reorder to a few columns?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In my WPF application, I am using a DataGrid control. I allow the user to reorder columns. However, I have to ensure that the first two columns and the last column cannot be reordered.

All the columns are generated programmatically using `new DataGridTextColumn()`.

I am wondering if someone can guide me on what I need to do to accomplish this? Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: I really don't know, but my first impression was when you hook on the Drag-Events, you could identify your sender and disable dragging for this item.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`DataGrid.FrozenColumnCount` Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.frozencolumncount%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to not allow the users to move columns.
However, if you look at the documentation, you will see that you can only do this for the first *x* columns *from the left side* of the `DataGrid`. For example, if you set the `FrozenColumnCount` to `2`, the two left columns in the display are frozen.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataGridColumn.CanUserReorder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridcolumn.canuserreorder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property (set tis property to `false` for columns, which can't be reordered).